# Find and replace strings in a python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, replace

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
d = {'alleged': ['truths', 'fiels', 'fact', 'infidelity', 'incident'],
 'greased': ['axle', 'wheel', 'wheels', 'fields', 'enGine', 'pizza'],
 'plowed': ['fields', 'field', 'field', 'incident', '', '']}
```

I would like to go over it and replace some items for another strings. The strings to be find and the ones to replace them are also in a dictionary, in which the key is the string to be found and the value is the string to replace it:

```
d_find_and_replace = {'wheels':'wheel', 'Field': 'field', 'animals':'plants'}
```

I tried to use a function like:

```
def replace_all(dic1, dic2):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        dic3 = dic1.replace(i, j)
    return(dic3)
```

but it won't work because obviously, it uses replace built-in function `replace` inside it, and it is not possible to use it for dictionaries. Any suggestions on how to do this? Thank you very much for any help.

**Edited to correct spelling mistakes.**

Comment: your `d_find_and_replace` dict is a bit of a mess.  Check that your quotes are in the right places.

Comment: your `d` dictionary also has several errors (no opening quote on `alleged`, close bracket inside the `greased` list). Clean those up so it works first then you can debug the replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try just using direct assignation:

```
for key in d:
    li = d[key]
    for i,item in enumerate(li):
        li[i] = d_find_and_replace.get(item, item)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This goes over only line of the dictionaries. Maybe it need to incorporate list comprehension?

Comment: @user2962024 erm.  I don't follow.  This goes through every `key` in `d` and does a `find_and_replace` operation on every list item for that key.  Did you want to build a new `dict` instead of mutating `d` in-place?

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I am sorry, I messed up something, but now I figured it out. Very nice solution! I really thank you for this!

Answer (score -1):

here is a solution. I also fixed your dictionaries they were messy. Check your spelling because with those given keys I think there is only going to be one match that will be replaced. for example `engine` will never match `enGine`, unless you don't care to match lower or upper case, in that case you can use `if val.lowercase()`

```
d = {'alleged': ['truths', 'fiels', 'fact', 'infidelity', 'incident'],
     'greased': ['axle', 'wheel', 'wheels', 'fields', 'enGine', 'pizza'],
     'plowed': ['fields', 'field', 'field', 'incident', '', '']}

d_find_and_replace = {'fields': 'field', 'engine': 'engine', 'incidint':'incident'}

keys_replace = d_find_and_replace.keys()
print d
for key in d.keys():
    for i, val in enumerate(d[key], 0):
        if val in keys_replace:
            index_to_replace = keys_replace.index(val)
            d[key][i] = d_find_and_replace[keys_replace[index_to_replace]]

print d
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I think this is python 2, is it not? I get the error: AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'index', do you know what is the equivalent for python 3.2? Thanks again!

Comment: I didnt use any `dict_keys` in the code I posted. Can you edit your answer with the code that is giving you the error.

Comment: I updated my answer, I think the problem was that I was using `index` as a local variable in the for loop and `index` as function. I replaced the `index` variable with `i`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I am sorry, no difference, still getting the message: `AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'index' referring to            `index_to_replace = keys_replace.index(val)`.

Comment: weird, what does `print keys_replace` it should be a list `['engine', 'fields', 'incidint']`